# Basic Logic: Understanding when premises are consistent

Tags: logic

According to my readings, for premises to be consistent, it's sufficient to check if there exists one interpretation of the conjunction of the premises that is true. (i.e. there is at least one entry in the truth table where the premises can all be true together)

Could someone please explain why the definition of consistency does not require the conjunction of premises to be a tautology instead? (or am I mistaken?) My reasoning is that if the conjunction of the premises could sometimes be false (hence not a tautology), then this would permit us to infer false conclusions using the rules of derivation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the inference "*if $n$ is an even integer then $n^2$ is an even integer*". `if the conjunction of the premises could sometimes be false` The premise "*if $n$ is an even integer*" *is* false for all odd integers. `then this would permit us to infer false conclusions` How?

Comment: I see, many thanks! My mind was a bit muddled. This clears things up :)

Comment: *tautology* means "the premises all true together in **every** entry"

Comment: Why are you asking about *premises* being consistent rather than asking about any set of propositions being consistent?  Do you think there would be a different set of rules for propositions in premises vs not in a premise?